# How get Id of element when i click on the element

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have 2 div(HTML) element and id is div1 and div2, When I click on any div then I want id of current div... idea?

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>

<div id="displayid"></div>
```

```
if(clickedDivId = this.id){
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var divCount = div.length;
var clickedDivId;
for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i += 1) {

    div[i].onclick = function(e) {
        clickedDivId = this.id;
        event.stopPropagation();

    };
} 
}

document.getElementById("displayid").innerHTML = ??clickedDivId??how;
```

Comment: `displayed on the screen by click`--on click of what exactly?

Comment: Should be `if(clickedDivId == this.id){`

Comment: with jQuery, you can bind the `click` event to the `document` object, and then check what is the target: `$(document).click(function(event) { console.log(event.target); });`

Comment: Each element is clicked .. if I click on div1 to display its name, by clicking on div2 to display its name, div3, div4......

Comment: @aldin_abdagic - `div1` is `id` property value and not `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try by modifying your own code

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var divCount = div.length;
var clickedDivId;
for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i += 1) {

    div[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        clickedDivId = this.id;        
        document.getElementById("displayid").innerHTML = this.id;

    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `this.id` to get `id` of clicked div.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div')
    .forEach(div => {
        div.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log(this.id);
        })
    })
```

```html
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div 2</div>

<div id="displayid">Div 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  var divToDisplay = event.target.id
  document.getElementById('displayid').innerHTML = divToDisplay
})
```

```html
<div id="div1">DIV TEST 1</div>
<div id="div2">DIV TEST 2</div>

<div id="displayid"></div>
```